# Insert into database postgres with october cms

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller, october-partial

Hi all I am new into october cms and I am facing trouble that makes my head spinning around. I have a form that get data from user, I am using builder.
This is my form :

```
{% put sudah %}{% partial "expert/yes"  %}{% endput %}

{% put styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap"> 
  
{% endput %}


<div class="text-center bg-primary">
    <h4 class="text-white my-auto py-5 title-menu">Expert Registration Form</h4>
</div>
```

```
 <div class="opening" id="first-menu">
    <p>Expert Registration Form</p>
    <button onclick="changeMenu()" class="btn btn-primary">
        Bergabung
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</div>


 <div class="tab-content d-none pb-4" id="second-menu">
   <div class=" container">
        <div class="head-menu">
            <p>Have you registered yet ?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2">
            <div class="form-check my-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioPick" id="yes" value="yes" checked>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radioPick">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check my-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioPick" id="no" value="no">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radioPick">No</label>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="btn-next mt-4">
            <button onclick="secondMenu()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="yes" class="d-none">
    {% placeholder yes%}
 </div>
```

```
{% put scripts %}
   <script>
        const changeMenu = () => {
            $( "#first-menu" ).addClass('d-none');
            $( "#second-menu" ).removeClass('d-none');
        }


        const secondMenu = () => {
          let radio = $('input[name=radioPick]:checked').val()
          $( "#second-menu" ).addClass('d-none');

          if(radio === 'yes'){
                $( "#yes" ).removeClass('d-none');
            }
         }

   </script>
{% endput %}
```

Then if yes, form for yes appeared
this is yes form :

```
<form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="example" class="something">

<input type="hidden" name="handler" value="onSave">

{{ form_token() }}
{{ form_sessionKey() }}

<div class="tab-content py-4" id="second-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-letter tab">
            <p class="title-letter">Please Fill This Form</p>

        <div class="content-letter tab">
            <div class="mt-3">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold">Nama</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name"
                            id="name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold">Phone</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" name="phone"
                            id="phone" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label class="text-dark font-weight-bold">Signature</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-9 col-md-10">
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" id="signature" class="custom-file input-file"
                                        name="signature" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
                                    <label id="label-sign" for="sign"
                                        class="custom-file-label label-files">Upload Signature</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button
            id="btn-okay"
            type="submit"
            data-request="onSave"
            data-hotkey="ctrl+s, cmd+s"
            data-load-indicator="Creating New..."
            class="btn btn-primary">
            Join
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

and in code section I wrote this function :

```
function onSave() {
$expert= new Expert();
$model = new \Models\Expert;

$expert->name = Input::get('name');
$expert->phone = Input::get('phone');
$expert->sign= Input::file('signature');

$expert->save();
return Redirect::back;

//or even this one
/*$nama = Input::get('name');
$phone = Input::get('phone');
$sign = Input::file('signature');

DB::table('expert')->insert([
    'name' => $name,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'sign' => $sign
]);
return Redirect::back;*/
```

}

and not forget I attach model in expert model :

```
 public $attachOne = [
    'signature' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

Please help me, what is wrong with my code ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documents](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#basic-inserts) out on working with models. Your php function should be:

```
use Author\Plugin\Models\Expert;
function onSave() {
    $expert= new Expert;

    $expert->name = Input::get('name');
    $expert->phone = Input::get('phone');
    $expert->sign = Input::file('signature');

    $expert->save();
    return Redirect::back;
}
```